# copy the content of a cell in one work book and convert it to an age

Tags: c#

I am trying to link the content of a cell in worksheet 1, to a cell in worksheet 2, i then want it to change the letter to a number (a persons age) which has been worked out in the column before it.

I thought that i could use the IF function ie IF attendance sheet c1= H,E,A,S1,S2 (attendance charge codes) if true replace with D1 (which is the persons age)

i have tried lots of different formulas including IF, Lookup, convert, and lots of other useless ones.

One that almost works is the concatenate formula as it gives me the results i need but it doesn't ignore blank cells and it puts the letter in front of the number

I am not overly good with formulas but am learning so any help provided will be gratefully accepted

Kind regards. Sharon

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at macros, its meant for these purposes.